# How to define bit literals in Go?

Tags: go

Is there any way to define bit literals like `var i=0b0001111` in Golang (**1.12v**)  as in C and some other languages?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals is an exhaustive list of integer literal expressions that are allowed. You might be able to come up with a convention using bit-shifts, bitwise-or, and/or the `iota` keyword to express these sorts of values.

Comment: Go is adding binary literals using the `0b` notation in [Go 1.13](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> The Go Programming Language Specification
>    Version of May 14, 2019
>
> Integer literals
>
> An integer literal is a sequence of digits representing an integer
>   constant. An optional prefix sets a non-decimal base: 0b or 0B for
>   binary, 0, 0o, or 0O for octal, and 0x or 0X for hexadecimal. A single
>   0 is considered a decimal zero. In hexadecimal literals, letters a
>   through f and A through F represent values 10 through 15.
>
> For readability, an underscore character _ may appear after a base
>   prefix or between successive digits; such underscores do not change
>   the literal's value.
>
> ```
> int_lit        = decimal_lit | binary_lit | octal_lit | hex_lit .
> decimal_lit    = "0" | ( "1" … "9" ) [ [ "_" ] decimal_digits ] .
> binary_lit     = "0" ( "b" | "B" ) [ "_" ] binary_digits .
> octal_lit      = "0" [ "o" | "O" ] [ "_" ] octal_digits .
> hex_lit        = "0" ( "x" | "X" ) [ "_" ] hex_digits .
>
> decimal_digits = decimal_digit { [ "_" ] decimal_digit } .
> binary_digits  = binary_digit { [ "_" ] binary_digit } .
> octal_digits   = octal_digit { [ "_" ] octal_digit } .
> hex_digits     = hex_digit { [ "_" ] hex_digit } .
> ```

---

For Go 1.13 and later, use binary or hexadecimal:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    b := byte(0b00010011)
    fmt.Printf("%08b %02x\n", b, b)
    x := byte(0x13)
    fmt.Printf("%08b %02x\n", x, x)
}
```

Output:

```
00010011 13
00010011 13
```

---

For Go 1.12 and earlier, use hexadecimal:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := byte(0x13)
    fmt.Printf("%08b %02x\n", x, x)
}
```

Output:

```
00010011 13
```